# I want to use post title as tag in wordpress. Is there anyway to automate the process instead of copy and paste one by one?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 1k of Wordpress posts, I want to use post title as tag. Is there anyway to automate the process instead of copy and paste one by one?

Comment: so you want to run the query which will run once and simply add all the post's title to tag as well ?

Comment: Yes, If there any possible way to do this?

Comment: you can do some trick in wordpress' function.php file .. by adding some hook or something ... which will find all the post with its respective id and title and then can use wordpress' this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags

Comment: make sure you need to execute only once.. as you have already added posts

Comment: first try to get all the posts in array using wordperss' init hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

Comment: if you are getting all the posts based on your requirements, then simply foor loop it and use wp_set_post_tags inside that loop .. i think this should do the trick for you..

Comment: please take backup of your database before doing anything to be safe side if you are supposed to do on live or do in your local server to make sure the things.

Comment: @Mit.agile. If you don't mind I asked too many questions.

I use Yoast SEO Plugin. All my posts doesn't has focus keyword added. Is there any way possible I can add the title to focus keyword field like post tag. So I can see my SEO score tested for every article i have. 

Highly appreciate :)

Comment: check this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-using-the-focus-keyword-in-php

Comment: I'm still working with this but no result. I want to get the page title into the field. Do you got any other method?
https://postimg.org/image/43k211hgr/

Comment: I want to paste post title to the "focus keyword" field of Yoast SEO of every post in my blog just like the way to automate the post tag.

Comment: yes https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-using-the-focus-keyword-in-php follow this link .. did u follow ?

Comment: Where should I place this code <?php wpseoFocusKW();?>

 then?

Comment: Place this code where you want the Focus Keyword to display.

Comment: I'm working around but not getting what I want. :(

Comment: tell me the issue or bug or error you are getting

Comment: Poor me, But I'm not really understand where to place the code to get my post title appear in this field.
https://postimg.org/image/wz3g5wo45/

Comment: where you are showing your keys ? is it meta keys you are talking about ? if so then header.php should be the file. check once.

Comment: ok if i m getting you right, you want to add different focus keyword for the all the posts which you have so far dynamically just like we did for tag for all posts .. correct ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I want.

Comment: is this the plugin you are using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ ? plz confirm

Comment: Sure it's that one.

Comment: fyi, you need find a hook if wordpress or plugin developers of yoast provided or not .. check once

Comment: and you can always raise this question in stack at last.

Comment: its a pleasure ... btw .. if u r supposed to raise a question or got any conclusion, please add link here or find a solution here so that i can follow and can come to know how you solved it ..

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848180/how-to-copy-title-of-wp-post-dynamically-to-focus-keyword-field-in-yoast-seo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code

```
add_action( 'init', 'default_function' );

function default_function() {

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );


    foreach ($posts_array as $current_post) {

        $post_id = $current_post->ID;
        $post_title = $current_post->post_title;

        wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $post_title, true );

    }


}
```

Add above code in your functions.php file

please make sure you only need to execute this once and then remove it from your functions.php file. However i have set 'true' in wp_set_post_tags as third parameter which will append the tags for particular post.

Comment: Highly appreciate for your help.
I have one more question Is that possible if I want to add extra word .i.e  "Post Title" + "Some words"?

Comment: @SambathDreamHigh of course you can ..  just append $post_title = $current_post->post_title . 'your custom word here';

Answer (score 0):

yes you can post automatic blog post on wordpress. 
here wordpress autopost plagins you may get your solution
[Wordpress auto poster](http://wp-autopost.net/)