# I want to use post title with custom words as tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to use post title with custom word as tag in wordpress for all posts. For example, I have the title "How to Create a Post in WordPress" and I would like the tag to look like "How to Create a Post in WordPress guide", "guide" is my word that I would like to add to each tag along with the name of the post. I have about 500 posts and would like to automatically add a tag with the post name + my custom word to all posts

I found something like this, but I don't know how to modify it to add a custom word to the post title

[I want to use post title as tag in wordpress. Is there anyway to automate the process instead of copy and paste one by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842257/i-want-to-use-post-title-as-tag-in-wordpress-is-there-anyway-to-automate-the-pr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code [from the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842257/i-want-to-use-post-title-as-tag-in-wordpress-is-there-anyway-to-automate-the-pr), and replace this:

```
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $post_title, true );
```

with this:

```
$tag_title = $post_title . ' Guide';
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tag_title, true );
```